# CSS display-table + SPAN error

Tags: html, css, alignment, fieldset

I have this example:
[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/aGLWP)

A table using display: table, display: table-cell, display: table-row

I need add before <p> a <span> tag, but my table structure **breaks**.

Any idea? Thanks

Example:

```
<fieldset>
<span>
<p>
    <label>First Name: </label>
    <input type="text" />
</p>
</span>
<span>
<p>
    <label>Second Name: </label>
    <input type="text" />
</p>
</span>
<span>
<p>
    <label>Country: </label>
    <select>
        <option>Choose</option>
    </select>
</p>
</span>
<span>
<p>
    <label>Age: </label>
    <select>
        <option>Choose</option>
    </select>
</p>
</span>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to display as a table then all elements should follow the same structural property's

```
fieldset span {
    display: table-row-group;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qQ3xJ/

Answer (score 1):

You're wrapping `table-row` elements (`<p>` tags in this case) by `<span>`. You could change the type of display of `<span>` elements to `table-row-group`:

```css
fieldset span {
    display: table-row-group;
}
```

Here is the **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/aGLWP/2/)**

Comment: Damn you beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different structure like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7Kxf5/, with `div` or a `ul` list.

I don't think using `span` in this case would fit in a good practice.